# Magento multiregion setup with 2 regions and 2 currencies

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

i'm lost with the magento outdated documentation. trying to set up a multiregion site.

regions should be magento-example.com/eu magento-example.com/us
eu with euros and us with dollars as currency. not automagicly converted.. 2 separate prices.

when trying to access /eu i get 404 but baseurl is set properly - do i have to set these env variables?

```
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "eu"
SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "website"
```

does someone know a good current tutorial on creating multisites based on paths not domains?

thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the RewriteBase for the eu/us folders? also, check: http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/setting-up-magento-with-multiple-websites-or-stores

Comment: i don't have any rewrites for /eu /us do i need some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it's pretty simple to set up a multiwebsite with path/subdirectories on same domain.

just create the second website/store/storeview and be sure to check 'Add Store Code to Urls' in settings > configuration > web then you can access your store with the storeview code mystore.com/storeviewcode

leave baseurl on both websites the same.